# obj model exported from SketchUp problems

Tags: three.js, sketchup

I export models from SketchUp which i downloaded from 3D warehouse to obj model format with materials and load them in THREE.js using OBJMTLLoader, the problem is those files are ver slow to load although they have small size not more than 1 MB, what is the problem in it and how can i fix this if no way where can i find free 3d obj models?

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console? If using Chrome, you can watch the loading progress in the 'network' tab in he development tools.

Comment: This link will search all free .obj files on turbosquid: http://www.turbosquid.com/Search/3D-Models/free/obj